# Reinstall windows on peppermint

Tags: windows-7, linux, ubuntu

Someone I know who has windows 7 was put on peppermint but after using it they decided they didn’t like it and wanted to go back to windows. Is it possible to re-install windows on a peppermint computer and how?

Answer (score 2):

It's definitely possible, and it's essentialy the same as installing Windows on a brand new computer - you get a Windows installation USB drive, boot from it (plug it in, then restart the computer), and go through the wizard.
 There are plenty of guides to do this (Microsoft's official https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/install-windows-from-a-usb-flash-drive).
There's also one for Windows7: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows7
Just be sure to copy your important personal files from the peppermint, because Windows will most likely do a clean install, wiping the drive clean.

Comment: Thanks, @Liudvikas  Akelis, but I want to install windows 7 not windows 10. Also, is it possible to install it from a CD and not a USB stick?

Comment: Thanks for the upvotes, but I'm really just googling things for you at this point

Comment: Hi @LiudvikasAkelis , The person who wants to install windows doesn’t have their product key. What should I do now? The guy that installed peppermint also said windows was still there.

Comment: Right. Usually when people install Linux alongside Windows (rather than writing over), they will leave an option for switching in the bootloader. If that's the case, you will see that option during boot (when computer turns on, before loading the operating system). There will be some sort of menu with Windows as an option.
If you are unable to find such menu during boot, that doesn't necessarily mean that Windows isn't there. However, at that point you really need hands-on help (any moderately seasoned IT person), but that kind of personal support is kinda beyond the scope of this site :/

Comment: Is there a stackexchange site where i could get that kind of support???

Answer (score -2):

Yes its possible,follow the below steps:

Step 1.Take out all your backup from the pc, so that you wont lose any data.
Step 2.Run GParted or any other application to clean your disk related to peppermint.
Step 3.Install the windows version that you like.